# Android take photo - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-activity, error-handling, android-camera

I am taking to take a photo in my Activity and I am getting this error :

The activity load ok, when I press to take a photo it then crash.

```
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at com.example.CameraActivity$1.onPictureTaken(CameraActivity.java:287)
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:855)
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5449)
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-24 17:22:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(32764):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

nnnnnnnn nnnnnnnnnnnn nnnnnnnnnnnn nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
here is the park of my code:

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.e("camera test", "1111");
        File pictureFile = new File( outFile ); //********* LINE 287
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
            return;
        }
        /*
        imageCrop(data, pictureFile, 0, (int)(1200 / 720 * top_px), 1200, 1200);

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("capturedFile",pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        finish();
        */

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            Bitmap btemp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outFile,options);

            Log.e("picture captured", options.outHeight + "|" + options.outWidth);

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("capturedFile",pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);

            finish();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
};
```

-----------------------UPDATE CODE -------------------------------------------------------------------

I am have a fragment which calls a custom take picture activity.

The intent extra passing to the activity call does not work. If I print the logcat I can see the intent in the Fragment. But the Activity does not receive it.

Fragment :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();           
intent.setClass(getActivity(), CameraActivity.class);   


Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra("outFile", fileUri);                    

    Log.e(TAG, "" +
            "------------------------------------------------------ " +
            "fileUri intent => " + fileUri);

startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

Intent intent = getIntent();
outFile = intent.getStringExtra("outFile");

String test = getIntent().getExtras().getString("outFile");

Log.i("CameraActivity", "" +
        "- " +
        "test intent => " + test);


Log.e("CameraActivity", "" +
        "- " +
        "intent.getStringExtra(outFile) => " + intent.getStringExtra("outFile"));  

Log.e("CameraActivity", "" +
        "- " +
        "outFile intent => " + outFile);
```

LogCat:

from fragemnt:

```
12-26 11:12:21.399: E/PostProductFragment(3563): - fileUri intent => file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20141226_111221.jpg
```

from activity log:

```
12-26 11:12:21.449: I/CameraActivity(3563): - test intent => null
12-26 11:12:21.449: E/CameraActivity(3563): - intent.getStringExtra(outFile) => null
12-26 11:12:21.449: E/CameraActivity(3563): - outFile intent => null
```

Comment: so `outFile` is null, did you check that?

Comment: Check the value of `outFile` have you initialized it?

Comment: Looks like your variable outFile is null. Where do you initialize it? Try to use the Debugger to get more information.

Comment: onCreate - Intent intent = getIntent();
        outFile = intent.getStringExtra("outFile"); Something is wrong here. thanks

Comment: if `outFile` is null it will be catched in IOException.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
     fileUri1 = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
     cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri1);
            }
        });
```

after returning to call this method:

```
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.host_img_showlogo);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri1.getPath(), options);
            Image_path= fileUri1.getPath();     
        }
```

Comment: Hiya, thank for your reply. I have added a update code above showing the null intent problem. Could you have a look please. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for taking photos on my app and this works fine, try this:

```
Intent c = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(c, FROM_CAMERA);


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == FROM_CAMERA  && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data )
        {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

           //Post here your code to get the path of the photo   

        }   

    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hiya, thank for your reply. I have added a update code above showing the null intent problem. Could you have a look please. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try check for

```
if (data != null)
```

because there may be numerous causes for data to be **null**.

UPDATE :

```
intent.putExtra("outFile", fileUri);
```

to

```
intent.putExtra("outFile", fileUri.toString());
```

Comment: Hiya, thank for your reply. I have added a update code above showing the null intent problem. Could you have a look please. thank you.